# Draggable Button Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, button, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

How can i create a draggable button in Xamarin.Android ?

I try to create by creating view, But it's not working at all.

Anyone have some idea or sample codes about it will be appreciated !

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Check this link  https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-supporting-drag-and-drop-in-an-app/

Comment: @Sreeraj : That blog is not well written. I tried to implement it, but failed.

Comment: I had not tried that example. But I am sure my answer below will work. I had used it successfully earlier.

Comment: Okay, Let me try once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `OnTouchListener`. Listen `OnTouch` events for the button and update the Layout of the button accordingly in `Move` Event. Here is Xamarin's [example](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/detect_a_touch/)

Comment: I want a draggable button, Not an ordinary draggable view. It must be capable of differentiating single click and drag.
By using `Move`, i implemented dragging property.
How can implement click property ?

Comment: One easy way would be to set a bool flag isMoving and set it to false on Down, set it True in Move and check for it's value in Up. In Up if it is true, don't do anything. Otherwise write your click callback

Answer (score 0):

1)extend the class for View.IOnDragListener
2)set on drag listener button.SetOnDragListener(this);
3)set long click event for button

```
void ButtonLong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (utility.IsHomeEditMode&&shortcutList.Count>1)
        {
            View view = (View)sender;

            //get the saved index of the corresponding view
            draggedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(view.GetTag(Resource.String.keyval));

            droppedIndex = -2;

            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String)view.GetTag(Resource.String.keyval));
            ClipData clipData = new ClipData((String)view.GetTag(Resource.String.keyval),
                        new String[] { ClipDescription.MimetypeTextPlain }, item);
            view.StartDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(view), null, 0);

            view.Visibility = (ViewStates.Invisible);

        }
    }
```

implement the onDrag method

```
       public bool OnDrag(View view, DragEvent e)
    {

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Started:

                return true;
            case DragAction.Entered:

                return true;
            case DragAction.Exited:

                return true;
            case DragAction.Drop:

                droppedIndex = Convert.ToInt16(view.GetTag(Resource.String.keyval)); ;
                return true;
            case DragAction.Ended:

                return true;

        }
        return false;

    }
```

update views inside the drop